# Throwing from before a try...catch

Tags: c++, exception

If I have something like this:

```
if(condition1)
{
    cout<<"ERROR: Expected an identifier \n.";
    throw std::invalid_argument(""); 
}

if(condition2)
{
    moveToken();
    cout<<"ERROR: Expected a ' ( ' after Identifier \n.";
    throw std::invalid_argument("");
}

moveToken();

try
{
    try
    {
        newPosition = position;
        fcNode->addChild(actual_params());
    }
    catch(exception &e)
    {
        position=newPosition;

        if(condition3)
        {
           moveToken();
           cout<<"ERROR: Expected a ' ) '  \n.";
           throw std::invalid_argument("");
        }

        moveToken();
        return fcNode;
    }

    if(condition4)
    {
        moveToken();
        cout<<"ERROR: Expected a ' ) '  \n.";
        throw std::invalid_argument("");
    }
}
catch (exception &e)
{
    moveToken();
    throw std::invalid_argument("");
}
```

Would the exception thrown from the `condition1` block be caught by any `catch` block or do I need to put the whole code in another `try` block and do a `catch` for it? (do `throw`s get caught by first encountered `catch` blocks?) Thanks

Comment: No, a throw is only caught if its in a `try { foo(); bar(); throw X(); } catch (X &) { ... }` block, where something in `foo()`/`bar()` can throw it too. They are caught in the first matching *outward/containing* catch block, not the next catch block *down*.

Comment: Hello, this is a good question. The exceptions in C++ work on a try/catch basis and it is possible to nest these exceptions, so the catch you are intending to use would refer to the closest try. if you were to use the first try, and you had 3 try's after that, you would need four catches, with the fourth catch corresponding to the first try.

Comment: much of the point of exceptions is to move the failure handling code out of the normal case business code. for the kind of nested structure you have it would be better with just if-else. here exceptions just mess up the code, while with proper use they clean it.

Comment: if you are in a catch block, you can rethrow the exception you are currently handling with a plain `throw` ex: `try{/*...*/} catch (...) { throw;/*rethrows*/ }`

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You generally do not need to nest `try` blocks since you can catch multiple types. `try{ ... } catch( invalid_argument& e ){ ... } catch( exception& e ) { ... }`. You should be catching specific types of exceptions. And don't create a new exception to throw in your catch blocks, just rethrow the original using `throw;` Sure there are exceptions to these exception handling rules, but break them cautiously.

Comment: I've removed the redundant `else` blocks from your code to make it easier to see what's going on.  The code flow is still the same; you don't need `else` because when an exception is thrown, execution jumps to an exception handler (or aborts the program if there is no handler); it can't "fall down" to the next line.

Comment: Consider replacing `cout << "errormessage"; throw x("");` with `throw x("errormessage");`. Then the enclosing code can decide how to handle the error. Also, you could restructure your later nested try...catch to be a lot simpler.

Comment: An exception is only caught by `catch` blocks which lexically enclose the point at which the exception is thrown or propagated.

Comment: @MattMcNabb will the message in the throw x(""); be displayed? because in my case I get no output if I do not use the cout. Thanks

Comment: @Kar you write code to display it after catching it, if you want it displayed. The point is that your surrounding `try..catch` block should have the option to `cout <<` it (or better, `cerr <<` it), or take some other action such as writing a log file.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I did not understand.. is it printed out or not by throw... or you need to use cout anyway?

Comment: `throw` does not print anything out.

Comment: thanks... where should I do the cout though? if I do the cout in the catch it is still printed even if the try does not throw an exception, I am confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following code:

```
try{
    // block 1
}catch(exception){
    // block 2
}
```

Every `exception` ONLY from `block 1` will be caught and processed by `block 2`; `catch` block cannot catch any exception outside of `block 1`, so yes, you have to make one more try-catch

Answer (score 2):

The execption will be caught by a type-matching `catch` block attached to whatever `try` block is enclosing the throw.  If no `try` block is enclosing the throw in the current scope, or none of the attached catch blocks match the exception's type, then the exception will be sent up the call chain (i.e. to whatever function called this one).  Repeat until we reach main, where the program will be terminated if the exception is not caught.

In the code you highlighted, there is no enclosing `try` block around that throw, so the exception will be handled further up the call chain, if at all.

Comment: It may be useful to say that execution changes to the *first* type-matching `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to put your hole code into a catch block since exception are only catch insde de surrounding try.

```
try { 
      //(.inside here can be catched.) 
} catch(const std::exception& ex){
      // here goes you catched exception 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, any type can be used for catching exceptions unlike in JAVA.
Ex:

```
try {
    int integer_ = 11;
    throw integer_;
} catch(int e) {
    std::cout<<e<<"\n";//Displays 11
}
```

You can use a multi catch block like:

```
try {
    int integer_ = 11;
    std::string string_ = "thrown exception";
    throw string_;
} catch(const std::string& e) {
    std::cout<<e<<"\n";//Displays thrown exception
} catch(int e) {//This block is not treated, beacause no integer is thrown as an exception
    std::cout<<e<<"\n";
}
```